# Where to type RequestHeader in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, requestheader

I need to add to prevent attack:

```
# a2enmod headers
 RequestHeader unset Range
 RequestHeader unset Request-Range
```

Where I can add it? This is my htttp.conf, maybe another file?

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /path/
<Location "/">
  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE projectname.settings
  PythonDebug Off
  PythonAutoReload Off
  PythonPath "['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django','/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sidt-packages/django/bin/projectname'] + sys.path"
</Location>

<Location "/media/">
  SetHandler None
</Location>

<Location "/static/">
  SetHandler None
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry, maybe I'm asking question without preparations, but I need to prevent attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

You can set this anywhere.  If you are doing it to prevent attacks you probably want to make it global, so put it above your first:

```
<VirtualHost>
```

declaration.

Answer (score 0):

according to Apache documentation context have to be:
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

so, not "anywhere". e.g. not in location context.

Comment: Not true, according to the documentation:

Directory:
A directive marked as being valid in this context may be used inside <Directory>, <Location>, <Files>, <If>, and <Proxy> containers in the server configuration files, subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.
.htaccess